# Переливающийся градиентный бэкграунд под анимацией css

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени! Проблема моя такова - есть блок с зеленым градиентным бэкграундом

```
<div class="blokolor"></div>
```

и вот такой css к нему

```
.blokolor {
width: 150px;
height: 40px;
dusplay: block;
background-color: black;

background: rgba(0,255,26,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,255,26,1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,255,26,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff1a',     endColorstr='#00ff1a', GradientType=0 );

-webkit-animation: animatebuton 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: animatebuton 2s linear infinite; 
}
```

Это, собственно, и есть зеленый градиент кнопки, мне нужно, чтобы кнопка плавно переливалась от зеленого в красный и обратно. Пробую делать так:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes animatebuton { 
0% {background: rgba(0,255,26,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,255,26,1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,255,26,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff1a', endColorstr='#00ff1a', GradientType=0 );
 } 

  100% {background: rgba(219,13,13,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(219,13,13,1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(97,40,40,1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%, rgba(97,40,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(219,13,13,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#db0d0d', endColorstr='#db0d0d', GradientType=0 );}


 }


  @-moz-keyframes animatebuton {
0% {background: rgba(0,255,26,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,255,26,1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%, rgba(44,99,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,255,26,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,255,26,1) 0%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(44,99,40,1) 85%, rgba(0,255,26,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff1a', endColorstr='#00ff1a', GradientType=0 );
 } 

  100% {background: rgba(219,13,13,1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(219,13,13,1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(97,40,40,1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(85%, rgba(97,40,40,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(219,13,13,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#db0d0d', endColorstr='#db0d0d', GradientType=0 );}

  }
```

Но все это почему-то не работает. Скажите, пожалуйста, что я неправильно тут намудрил, или, может, вообще такое невозможно сделать на чистом css?

Вот, кстати, тут можно глянуть код https://jsfiddle.net/3j0k995d/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимировать непосредственно градиент нельзя, поскольку он является значением свойства `background-image`, которое по стандарту не является анимируемым. Потому я предлагаю такое решение: наложить сверху вашей кнопки псевдоэлемент, у него будет фон с нужным вам градиентом. Этот псевдоэлемент будет по умолчанию прозрачным и анимировать мы будем его прозрачность.

P.S. обратите внимание на то, что вы используете древнейший сниппет по написанию градиентов. Если вы не собираетесь поддерживать мамонтов, то сократите его до одной строчки. Для анимации тоже достаточно максимум одного префикса — `-webkit`.

```css
@keyframes backgroundChange {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.blokolor {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 255, 26, 1) 0%, rgba(44, 99, 40, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 65%, rgba(44, 99, 40, 1) 85%, rgba(0, 255, 26, 1) 100%);
}

.blokolor:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(219,13,13,1) 0%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 65%, rgba(97,40,40,1) 85%, rgba(219,13,13,1) 100%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: backgroundChange 3s alternate-reverse infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class=blokolor></div>
```