# Как задать скорость перехода hover градиенту в css?

Tags: html, css, анимация, transition

Как задать скорость перехода `:hover` градиенту, чтобы переход был не таким резким:

```css
.posts-item__data {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 60px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #363636 55%, #252525 45%);
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 3px;
  }
  
.posts-item-data__number {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 9px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.posts-item-data__month {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 7px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
}

.posts-item__data:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C7B299 55%, #A48D72 45%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="posts-item__data">
   <span class="posts-item-data__number">32</span>
   <span class="posts-item-data__month">Sep.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переливающийся градиентный бэкграунд под анимацией css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636189/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-css)

Comment: Наверное нужно добавить в .posts-item__data: transition: all ease .5s;

Comment: transition не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Transition` не поддерживает градиенты. Вашу конкретную задачу, вы можете решить таким образом:

```css
.posts-item__data {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.posts-item-data__number {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #363636;
  transition: background 1s;
}

.posts-item-data__month {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 7px;
  height: 31px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #252525;
  transition: background 1s;
}

.posts-item__data:hover .posts-item-data__number {
  background: #C7B299;
}

.posts-item__data:hover .posts-item-data__month {
  background: #A48D72;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts-item__data">
  <span class="posts-item-data__number">32</span>
  <span class="posts-item-data__month">Sep.</span>
</div>
```

В случае, если градиент плавный, то можно задать его высоту в 2 раза больше блока, и плавным смещением `background-position` переместить фон на позицию нужного.

Comment: просто и со вкусом. Жаль, что редко отвечаете из-за дефицита со свободным временем.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо)